# what is Best practices for designing asynchronous task in this case( in kotlin, coroutine or thread)

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, callback, listener, coroutine

my android app need to call more than 10 APIs at the same time.
this call  api's is use other library it made in other teams
and result receive by listener in `JsonString` format.

this multiple calling api is need to call at same time.
Because it takes a lot of time to call one API

i made it by callback structure like this.
but i hope refactor this code covert to coroutine.

```kotlin
    private val library : OtherLibrary = OtherLibrary()
    private val retryCount: HashMap<String?, Int> = HashMap()
    private val listener = object : ApiListener {
        override fun onSucceeded(apiName: String, result: String?) {
            when (apiName) {
                "UserInfo" -> handleResultUserInfo(result)
                "ProductInfo" -> handleResultProductInfo(result)
                "....Info" -> handleResult___Info(result)
                // ... and Others
            }
        }
        override fun onUpdate(apiName: String, version: String) = library.callApi(apiName, this)
        override fun onFailed(apiName: String) = retry(apiName, this)
    }

    fun start() {
        callAPI("UserInfo")
        callAPI("ProductInfo")
        // ... and Others
    }

    fun callAPI(apiName: String, listener: ApiListener? = null) {
        val listener = listener ?: this.listener
        retryCount[apiName] = 0
        library.callApi(apiName, listener)
    }

    fun retry(apiName: String, listener: ApiListener) {
        if (retryCount[apiName]!! < 3) {
            retryCount[apiName]!!.plus(1)
            library.callApi(apiName, listener)
        }else{
            throw RuntimeException("API Call Failed: $apiName")
        }
    }

    fun handleResultUserInfo(result: String?) {
        // TODO parse & do something
    }

    fun handleResultProductInfo(result: String?) {
        // TODO parse & do something
    }

    fun handleResult___Info(result: String?) {
        // TODO parse & do something
    }

    // ... and Others
```

i want use coroutine for readability not callback structure.
callback structure is not good method for readability i think.

so, i applied `suspendCoroutine` to library's listener for look like synchronous readability.
but, `suspendCoroutine` is suspend it functions when to until call `it.resume`

## what is best practice in this case?

```kotlin
    private val library : OtherLibrary = OtherLibrary()
    private val retryCount: HashMap<String?, Int> = HashMap()

    fun start(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
            handleResultUserInfo(callAPI("UserInfo"))
            handleResultProductInfo(callAPI("ProductInfo"))
            handleResult___Info(callAPI("___Info"))
        }
    }

    suspend fun callAPI(apiName: String, listener:ApiListener? = null) : String? = suspendCoroutine{
        val listener = listener ?: object : ApiListener {
            override fun onSucceeded(apiName: String, result: String?) = it.resume(result)
            override fun onUpdate(apiName: String, version: String) = library.callApi(apiName, this)
            override fun onFailed(apiName: String) = retry(apiName, this)
        }
        retryCount[apiName] = 0
        library.callApi(apiName, listener)
    }
```

↑ it waiting complete of previous work. it's not call api at same time

so i try to like this.

```kotlin
    fun start(){
        val callDataArr = arrayOf(
            CallData("UserInfo", ::handleResultUserInfo),
            CallData("ProductInfo", ::handleResultProductInfo),
            CallData("___Info", ::handleResult___Info),
            // ... and others
        )

        callDataArr.forEach {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                it.handler(callAPI(it.apiName))
            }
        }
    }
```

but... it doesn't look good.

because, CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch called a lot of times

is not good for performance or have other problems?

Comment: What library are you using to call the API? Some libraries such as Retrofit/OKhttp already have suspend function support built in so you don’t have to use `suspendCoroutine`. It’s fine to call `launch` many times, but you should call them all on the same CoroutineScope instance. You should keep your CoroutineScope reference in a property so you can cancel of its work when appropriate, such as when this class goes out of scope of what the user is doing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 otherLibrary is made by other team working together. but i can't ask fix it. There are several business problems. and this library support just the call back structure. is not support suspend. so but i wish using coroutine for readability.